# Find pairs of integers (a, b) in an array such that a = b + k in linear time - elements are not unique

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, search-algorithms, arrays

A while ago, I was asked to solve a question similar to this:

> *We are given an array* `arr` *and we would like to find all pairs of items* `(a, b)` *where* `a = b + k`. The items are **NOT** unique and it is also possible to have `k = 0`.

I know that if items are unique, this problem can be solved in linear time by using a hashmap. However, when items are **NOT** unique, I think that the problem becomes very different.

See this example:

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
k = 0
```

The expected output is:

```
(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1) // For the first element
(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)         // For the second element
(1, 1), (1, 1)                 // For the third element
(1, 1)                         // For the fourth element
```

As it is obvious to me, in the worst case (the above example) the output is of size $n \choose 2$, which is $\Theta (n^2)$. How is it possible to have a linear algorithm, when the output size is definitely $\Theta (n^2)$?

My interviewer insisted that it is possible to still solve it in linear time, *if the correct data structure is used*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must write out all of the pairs individually, then the overall problem takes quadratic time because the running time of this last post-processing step is $O(n^2)$.

If you are allowed to represent the output in a different way, then you can simply keep track of distinct pairs and associate them with a counter (see [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)). Thus, you can compute the solution in $O(n)$ time using the following algorithm:

1. Initialize an auxiliary array (or hash map) $Aux$.
2. Perform a first linear scan of the input array $Arr$ and use the auxiliary array to keep track of how many times each of the elements appears. For example, $Aux[2]=3$ indicates that $2$ appears $3$ times in $Arr$.
3. Perform a second linear scan of the input array $Arr$. During the $i$th iteration, $a=Arr[i]$ and you must look for the element $b =a-k$, which appears $c =Aux[b]$ times in $Arr$. If $c \gt 0$, then you will add the pair $(a,b)$ to your solution, associated with the count $c$. Two special cases that must be considered at step 3:

   - If the pair already exists in your solution, you can simply increment the existing counter by $c$.
   - If $k=0$, you must add the pair $(a,b)$ only if $c \gt 1$. The counter associated with this pair will not be set to (or incremented by) $c$, but, rather, by $c-x-1$, where $x$ stores how many times we have seen $a$ before.

Comment: Let's give your solution a try for the given example `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. In our _Aux_ array, we have only `Aux[1] = 5`. At step 3, we are looking for `b = 1 - 0`; therefore, `c = Aux[b]` is `5`. We add 5 `(1, 1)` to our solution. At this point, it becomes clear that (for the next steps) to make sure we are not inserting repeated pairs, we have to check the indices. Therefore, the *count idea* does not apply here. You should know that elements are different, although they all have value 1.

Comment: Mmm, I think you misunderstood the second bulleted point (I am going to edit it, for clarification). If $k=0$, at step 3, iteration 0, you will add $(1,1)$ to your solution. The counter will be $c=5-0-1=4$, which is correct. At iteration 1, you will not add $(1,1)$, but rather increment its counter by $c=5-1-1=3$, which is also correct. At iteration 2, you will increment the counter by $c=5-2-1=2$, and so on ... for a final result of $(1,1)$  and counter equal to $10$.

Comment: In any case, you are printing `(1, 1)` 4 times the first time; 3 times the second time; 2 times the third time; and once for the last iteration. Thus, it is still $n \choose 2$. Please note that I was required to return the pairs, so **I had to print them**. If the question were _how many pairs are there?_ and we did not have to print them... Then yes; your solution would give us _that answer_ in linear time.

Comment: Well, if writing out all of the pairs individually is a requirement, then, IMHO, the overall problem does not take linear time (in contrast to the interviewer's suggestion): the solution can be computed in $O(n)$ time, but there is a post-processing step that takes $O(n^2)$ time.